# BLE Joystick / Gamepad - custom device name in Windows joy.cpl applet

Tags: bluetooth-lowenergy, hid, gatt, gamepad, bluetooth-gatt

A HID over GATT (HOGP) gamepad is visible in Windows 10 Game Devices applet (joy.cpl) as "8 axis 32 button device". The device has the following GATT Characteristics set under Device Information Service (0x180a):

1. PnP ID (0x2a50)
2. Device Name (0x2a00)
3. Model Name (0x2a24)

PnP ID is set to identity source 2 (USB), VID/PID combination is unique.

I need the device to be visible as "Custom Name" the same way as USB HID devices. I tried to set other optional characteristics for device information service (such as manufacturer name) without the desired effect.

Any suggestions how to setup the device to make Windows 10 show the custom name for that device correctly?

PS: I do not want to make a custom driver, edit registry under HKEY_CURRENT_USER\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\MediaProperties\PrivateProperties\Joystick\OEM or supply INF file for the device..

Comment: Have you tried to set the advertisement name or the Device Name characteristic in the Generic Access service? (https://www.bluetooth.com/specifications/gatt/viewer?attributeXmlFile=org.bluetooth.service.generic_access.xml)

Comment: Yes, this does set the device name in Windows Control Panel, Device Manager and Add/Remove Bluetooth Device dialog window.This does not affect Windows 10 Game Devices applet (joy.cpl), the device name stays the same here ("8 axis 32 button device")